# Chest/shoulder pain while running

Tags: running, pain, muscle-soreness

I am an on and off runner and this summer I took up running again. After chest pain began to show up, I saw a doctor to get it checked out. Heart issues were ruled out.

The pain is kind of a sore feeling across the top of my chest and is accompanied by muscle knots in my shoulders and sometimes in my pecs. For this reason, the doc thinks it's musculoskeletal in nature. It sometimes lasts for several days (though the pain fluctuates a good bit during the day) and is exacerbated by running.

Has anyone had a similar kind of problem or could shed light on what might be causing it? Could running form be the problem?

Comment: Some of these q/a may help: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14240/what-is-this-chest-pain-i-get-every-time-i-run, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/why-does-my-collarbone-hurt-while-jogging